# Add a select option of shortcodes like dropdown in tinymce

Tags: plugin-development, tinymce, wysiwyg, plugin-tinymce

I creeate an plugin where users creating own shortcodes. I want to add TinyMce support to users can select and place shortcode where they want. Can anyone gve me good explanation how to do that?

I need simple explanation how to made select option menu in tinymce.

I must note that my plugin use arround 2000 users on various WordPress versions and I must be carefull how to add that to not made some big problems between versions.

Thanks!